# When should we use a floating layout instead of a tiled layout in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

Options are :-

1. If we want to overlap your worksheets with a background image
2. If there are no consistent blank spaces in the dashboard
3. If you want lots of space between worksheets
4. If the dashboard size is set to Automatic

I'm new to this technology, and this was asked in a exam

Answer (score 0):

If we want to overlap your worksheets with a background image

- Yes. You floating objects would allow you to add workbooks over the top of background images.

If there are no consistent blank spaces in the dashboard

- You choose how much blank space is in your dashboard by the layout. Add blank tiles to add blank space, or move floating objects based on your preference.

If you want lots of space between worksheets

- Same as above, this is your choice depending on your visual preferences. Blank spaces can be added or removed with both tiled and floating objects.

If the dashboard size is set to Automatic

- If your dashboard size is set to automatic, floating objects will move around depending on the resolution of the screen. Not the best option for automatic dashboard size.